# How to save the rich text to fmdb?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, uitextview, fmdb

I use fmdb to store data, and UITextView has text, images and emojis in it, and I save it as following

```
Insert into table (content)values(?)
```

Here ? = UITextView.text

But the fmdb only stores the text content, no images and  emojis, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The text value of UITextView is a String, which is Unicode but may be getting reduced to ascii or similar for the database.

You'll want to explicitly store UTF8 data in the database either as a data blob or by specifying UTF8 as the column data type if supported.